# Preventing warnings from fsockopen

Tags: php, warnings, fsockopen

I use fsockopen() to connect to multiple servers in a loop.

However some servers are not valid and I get PHP warnings like the one below:

```
Warning: fsockopen() [function.fsockopen]: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: The requested name is valid, but no data of the requested type was found
```

Is there a way to prevent these warnings.

Like checking whether the server is good before trying to fsockopen it?

Or is there another or better solution for this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use the [error control operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php) and check the results of `fsockopen()` to verfiy you have a valid connection.

```
$rc = @fsockopen(...);
if (is_resource($rc))
{
   // do work
}
```