# error control operator not working

Tags: php

My question is similar to this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4330494/preventing-warnings-from-fsockopen). However, the [error control operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php) does not work for me.

With the following code:

```
$this->fp = @fsockopen($this->ip, $this->port, $errno, $errstr, $this->timeout);
```

I still get an error message:

`fsockopen(): unable to connect to xxx.xxx.xxx.xx:xxxxx (A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. )`

Is it possible that I can have error control operators disabled?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the problem! I've been using my own error handler

```
set_error_handler('my_error_handler');
```

and it prints out the errors irregardless if `@` has been prefixed or not.

FYI - code from the [php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php) demonstrates how errors can be suppressed within a user defined error handler:

```
// if error has been supressed with an @
if (error_reporting() == 0) {
    return;
}
```