# why two error reports when include() and require() failed in php

Tags: php

i have a script like this :

```
<html>
<body>

<?php
require("wrongFile.php");
echo "Hello World!";
?>

</body>
</html>
```

now if wrongfile not exists the two below error will report:

> Warning: require(wrongFile.php) [function.require]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\home\website\test.php on line 5
>
> Fatal error: require() [function.require]:Failed opening required 'wrongFile.php' (include_path='.;C:\php5\pear') in C:\home\website\test.php on line 5

i know that if not exists file in require() function a fatal error displayed that cause script execution stop but do not understand what is first error

the first error display in using of include() function too

Comment: You can also turn off warnings all together, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1645661/turn-off-warnings-and-errors-on-php-mysql

Comment: @everyone: do not format error messages as a code. you're making them worse than just plain text.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's pretty obvious, isn't it? :-)

The first warning is thrown from within the `require()` function, when it tries to open the file you specified. It can't open a stream, which is used to read the file, because the file doesn't exist.

Because of that, the function call itself also fails, which explains the 'Fatal error'.

Answer (score 0):

The first is warning, not error. You can try using `@include` to suppress it. (naturally, it's of no great use with `require`).

Comment: why, why this answer was ever upvoted? What can be even a slightest reason?