# How can I disable notices and warnings in PHP within the .htaccess file?

Tags: php, .htaccess

I just want to only turn on PHP errors and disable all notices and warnings in PHP files.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Turn off warnings and errors on php/mysql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1645661/turn-off-warnings-and-errors-on-php-mysql)

Answer (score 59, accepted):

It is probably not the best thing to do. You need to at least check out your PHP error log for things going wrong ;)

```
# PHP error handling for development servers
php_flag display_startup_errors off
php_flag display_errors off
php_flag html_errors off
php_flag log_errors on
php_flag ignore_repeated_errors off
php_flag ignore_repeated_source off
php_flag report_memleaks on
php_flag track_errors on
php_value docref_root 0
php_value docref_ext 0
php_value error_log /home/path/public_html/domain/PHP_errors.log
php_value error_reporting -1
php_value log_errors_max_len 0
```

Comment: Remembet to never send an error_log file to a public access location.

Comment: @glerendegui indeed, I am not suggesting this is best practice. Like the comment says for a simple development environment, not production its very handy to access the error log on your localhost||network.

Comment: @glerendegui can you explain why not send an error_log file to a public access location?

Comment: @Tarik error_log file may contain very sensitivy info about your app bugs. Leaving this file in a public environment looks very unsure. Anyone could try access yourdomain/error_log and access that info

Comment: Does this also disable the error show in mysql ? can anyone post related hide show error from sql that php handles and shows.

Answer (score 29):

If you are in a shared hosting plan that doesn't have PHP installed as a module you will get a 500 server error when adding those flags to the .htaccess file.

But you can add the line

```
ini_set('display_errors','off');
```

on top of your .php file and it should work without any errors.

Answer (score 24):

Try:

```
php_value error_reporting 2039
```

Comment: Nice! Can you please provide the logic behind the integer 2039?

Comment: The value 2039 stands for E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE. Found that here: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-debug/

Comment: when i put it in .htaccess it gives 500 internal error

Comment: @RajeshPatel this works with mod_php but not php-fpm. With php-fpm you can use SetEnv PHP_VALUE "error_reporting = 2039"

Comment: The value comes from the values of the constants PHP assigned to E_ALL and others. You can get the number using a simple echo on a php file doing as example `echo E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT & ~E_WARNING & ~E_NOTICE` which should be a string used usually on the php.ini

Answer (score 6):

Fortes is right, thank you.

When you have a shared hosting it is usual to obtain an `500 server error`.

I have a website with [Joomla](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joomla) and I added to the `index.php`:

```
ini_set('display_errors','off');
```

The error line showed in my website disappeared.

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
ini_set('display_errors','off');
```

It is working fine in WordPress' `wp-config.php`.

Comment: this is the only one that works. I have tried 20 different lines. This, works.

Comment: Do you mean file *wp-config.php*? Where is that file supposed to be located?

Answer (score 0):

I used `ini_set('display_errors','off');` and it worked great.