# include php file depending on which link is clicked?

Tags: php

I am trying to include several different php include files in my page attach.php which display 1 include file at a time depending on which link is clicked.

Here's my links:

```
 <a href="attach.php?tab=insurance"><div class="hewden_square"></div><h33>Insurance Documents</h33></a> 
 <a href="attach.php?tab=policy"><div class="hewden_square"></div><h33>Policy Documents</h33></a>
```

next I have my php code which checks which link has been clicked.

```
    <?php
switch(isset($_GET['tab'])) { //switch is just like a bunch of if()s
    default: //default case
    case '': //default case
    include('include/attachments_overview.php'); //include page.html
    break;  //break, witch means stop
    case 'insurance': // page2, if changePage has the value of page2
    include('include/upload_insurance/upload_files.php'); //include page2.html
    break;  //break, witch means stop
    case 'policy': // page2, if changePage has the value of page2
    include('include/upload_policy/upload_files.php'); //include page2.html
    break; //stop it
} //end the switch
?>
```

my default include file should be shown before any link is clicked and this is:

```
include('include/attachments_overview.php');
```

then one or the other should be included depending on which link is clicked.
For some reason my default include file is shown as expected and my other include file

```
include('include/upload_insurance/upload_files.php');
```

is shown when I click the link attach.php?tab=insurance

however when I click on my last link attach.php?tab=policy this just seems to show the same include file for my insurance tab

```
include('include/upload_insurance/upload_files.php');
```

can someone please show me where I am going wrong or show me a better/more reliable way of doing this? Thanks

Comment: it may be helpful; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21826691/include-php-files-inside-tab

Comment: isset($_GET['tab']) always returns 1.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$tb = isset($_GET['tab']) ? $_GET['tab'] : '';
switch($tb) { //switch is just like a bunch of if()s
    default: //default case
    include('include/attachments_overview.php'); //include page.html
    break;  //break, witch means stop
    case 'insurance': // page2, if changePage has the value of page2
    include('include/upload_insurance/upload_files.php'); //include page2.html
    break;  //break, witch means stop
    case 'policy': // page2, if changePage has the value of page2
    include('include/upload_policy/upload_files.php'); //include page2.html
    break; //stop it
} //end the switch
?>
```