# Suppress mysql errors on php

Tags: php, mysql, error-handling

I know that in general the php errors can be suppressed using error_reporting(0) or the '@'.
I have many sql queries being fired in a certain section of my work, I wanted to know that does adding error_reporting(0) suppress the appearance of errors arising from mysql queries?

I read online varying answers. Some state it will help while others say it wont work like that .

Comment: I do not want to add @ individually to all the calls. I am hoping for a more general answer.

Comment: [Possible Douplicate for this link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1987579/how-to-remove-warning-messages-in-php)

Comment: Try to solve them instead of suppressing them.

Comment: @Ravi-I have. Its actually an admin system so never really sure what might crop up ..:)

Comment: you can turn off error showing by htacces files also.Please try [this][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1645661/turn-off-warnings-and-errors-on-php-mysql

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try putting this at the top of your code:

```
ini_set("display_errors", "off");
```

And yes, adding `@` at the beginning of functions etc, for example:

```
$query = @mysql_query("text..");
```

Should suppress errors.

Comment: error_reporting(0) at the start of the script wont do the trick ?

Comment: and please explain how setting display_errors will be better than error_reporting. Thank you

Comment: @BhumiSinghal Several times I've tried `error_reporting(0);` and some errors still show up. Often I've been able to overcome this by also putting `ini_set("display_errors", "off");` at the top of my code. Just try it and see if it works for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you have htaccess file then you can controll all errors by this.
try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1645661/turn-off-warnings-and-errors-on-php-mysql)

Comment: I do have an htaccess but I am looking for the simplest possible solution ...and I guess php surely provides something to handle this :)