# How to avoid file_get_contents error: "Couldn't resolve host name"

Tags: php

I succesfully fetch websites with

```
file_get_contents("http://www.site.com");
```

However, if the url doesn't exist, or not reachable, I am getting

```
Warning: file_get_contents(http://www.site.com) [function.file-get-contents]: 
failed to open stream: operation failed in /home/track/public_html/site.php 
on line 773
```

Is it possible to `echo "Site not reachable";` instead of the error ?

Comment: try `@file_get_contents(...)` :)

Comment: Thanks. However, I have read somewhere that I should not use that @ because it's not a good way.

Comment: Duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/272361/how-can-i-handle-the-warning-of-file-get-contents-function-in-php.

Comment: @user198989 Using the `@` is **OK** if you handle the return value. It's *the way to go*

Comment: Could you specify "somewhere" then? You will not get it easier than adding one character to your code ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the [silence operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php) `@` together with [`$php_errormsg`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.phperrormsg.php):

```
if(@file_get_contents($url) === FALSE) {
    die($php_errormsg);
}
```

Where the `@` suppresses the error message, the message text will be available for output in `$php_errormsg`

But note that `$php_errormsg` is disabled by default. You'll have to turn on `track_errors`. So add at the top of your code:

```
ini_set('track_errors', 1);
```

However there is a way that does not depend on track errors:

```
if(@file_get_contents($url) === FALSE) {
    $error = error_get_last();
    if(!$error) {
        die('An unknown error has occured');
    } else {
        die($error['message']);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I would perfer to trigger exceptions instead of error messages:

```
function exception_error_handler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline ) {
    // see http://php.net/manual/en/class.errorexception.php
    throw new ErrorException($errstr, $errno, 0, $errfile, $errline);
}

set_error_handler("exception_error_handler");
```

Now you can catch the error like this:

```
try {
    $content = file_get_contents($url);
} catch (ErrorException $ex) {
    echo 'Site not reachable (' . $ex->getMessage() . ')';
}
```

Comment: But you will get yourself into deep trouble messing around with the error handler like this

Comment: `Working with @ can indeed be considered as wrong` LOL :D Yes, you presented a nice alternative but be careful when saying such things

Comment: @migg You could always restore the error handler with `restore_error_handler`

Comment: But you did not and did not mention it. And you do not `die()` in your error handler which lets all error code continue after throwing your exception... which can also be considered as wrong.

Comment: @hek2mgl If you really don't care about what error you got, I get why you'd use `@`. But in general you just want to handle the error you get, and dont just ignore them.

Comment: @migg the code will stop executing at the point of the error and jump to the catch

Comment: @sroes But all other errors that are not inside a try-catch will not.

Comment: @sroes I would advice you to just remove the first sentence. The remaining part of the answer is good

Comment: @hek2mgl I did not see the edit of `error_get_last`; didn't know about that function. But for using $php_errormsg: I personally always try to prevent situations where a variable magically appears, but I guess that's just part of PHP.

Comment: However, as I said, your proposal is good. But it's more suited for a global attempt, meaning catching all warnings and errors in a well defined way (therefore +1). But for local operations the `@` operator is still important and handy.. you'll see ;) .... I just wanted to point that both solutions have there advantages and disadvantages and neither of them is *wrong*

Comment: Yeah, you're right. It's not wrong to use it, it just depends on opinion and the context where it's used.

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
@file_get_contents("http://www.site.com");
```

The `@` suppresses warnings and errors to be output by PHP. You will have to deal with an empty response yourself then.

Answer (score 1):

You can use curl for avoid displaying php errors :

```
    $externalUrl = ** your http request **

    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $externalUrl); // Set the URL
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/34.0.1847.131 Safari/537.36'); // Use your user agent
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); // Set so curl_exec returns the result instead of outputting it.
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); // Bypass SSL Verifyers
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 5);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    ));

    $result = curl_exec($curl); // send request
    $result = json_decode($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can turn off warnings in PHP :

[Turn off warnings and errors on PHP and MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1645661/turn-off-warnings-and-errors-on-php-mysql)

See in documentation:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php

> Return Values: The function returns the read data or FALSE on failure.

or write @, before function, for avoid to see error:

@file_get_contents(...

Comment: Hmm, but errors are always good way to handle whats the problem, only this one is disgusting for me.

Comment: If fail request is can be many problems. Better way to work over PHP extension -  CURL, that if you want to know exactly what's happen, after request.

- Can be DNS request fail
- Wrong page 404, 501
- Server timeout.

Anyway you receive FALSE, if request is wrong. Not sure, if it need to do over exception..  Better anyway in production server to disable warnings.