# Hide php mysql constraint violation warning for selected functions

Tags: php, mysql, warnings

I am new to PHP and I am developing a project using http://www.php-mvc.net/ light php MVC framework.
I have a many to many mapping between two tables i.e

```
collection : id
profile : id
collection_profile : collection_id <--> profile_id
```

I have created a function where I insert mapping row in the collection_profile table.
Now the problem. I have create composite key of `collection_id` and `profile_id` so it wont let me enter duplication combination, that is what i want.

I have added these lines in try,catch block. but It still shows Warning: `PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation` on the page.

I found [error_reporting(E_ERROR)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1645661/turn-off-warnings-and-errors-on-php-mysql) but I am not able to figure out where to put this line. because I want to disable warning only for that function.

BTW, I am doing this because. I don't want to check if the row exist and then try to insert. I want mysql to do the work.

Let me know if you require anymore information.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In PHP, typing `@` before the statement lets you suppress any warnings it produces

```
@$stm->execute();
```

But still it would be much better if you understood why exactly the warning is issued. You're probably doing something wrong.

Edit:
You can suppress this warning on MySQL side by executing `INSERT IGNORE` instead of `INSERT`, see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert.html

Comment: I will try it. I am doing this because. I don't want to check if the combination does not exist and then try to insert. I want to let mysql do the work.

Comment: In this case, since you're using MySQL, you can do INSERT IGNORE to suppress the warning on MySQL side

Comment: I will do that. That is a better solution that adding @. Thanks Again.

Comment: I don't need to wrap the code try-catch then, right?

Comment: @AmitChotaliya right, no exceptions will be thrown. MySQL will simply do nothing, if the row already exists

Comment: BTW. I still had to add @ because. IGNORE just suppresses error but it generates warning.