# my ajax call is returning html with json data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am having a weird problem, I am trying to populate the datatable using ajax call to my php program which internally gets data from database.

php:

```
<?php
require_once('config.php');
$query = mysql_query("select * from productdetails");
while($fetch = mysql_fetch_array($query))
{
        $output[] = array ($fetch[0],$fetch[1],$fetch[2],$fetch[3],$fetch[4],$fetch[5]);
}
echo json_encode($output, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
?>
```

Html(ajax call):

```
$.ajax({
            url: 'process.php?method=fetchdata',
            data: "json",
            success: function(s){
            console.log($(s).text());
                    oTable.fnClearTable();
                        for(var i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
                         oTable.fnAddData([
                                    s[i][0],
                                    s[i][1],
                                    s[i][2],
                                    s[i][3],
                                    s[i][4],
                                    s[i][5]
                                           ]);                                      
                                        } // End For

            },
            error: function(e){
               console.log(e.responseText); 
            }
            });
```

This generates the output as

> ( ! ) Deprecated: mysql_connect(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead in C:\wamp\www\datatableone\process.php on line *2*
>   Call Stack
>   #TimeMemoryFunctionLocation
>   10.0010242552{main}(  )..\process.php**:**0
>   20.0010242840http://www.php.net/function.mysql-connect' target='_new'>mysql_connect
>   (  )..\process.php**:**2
>   
>   {"0":{"0":"1","1":"Iron","2":"AX12","3":"Google","4":"21.95","5":"HW"},"1":{"0":"2","1":"DartBoard","2":"AZ52","3":"Apple","4":"12.95","5":"SG"},"2":{"0":"3","1":"BasketBall","2":"BA74","3":"Microsoft","4":"29.95","5":"SG"},"3":{"0":"4","1":"Compopper","2":"BH22","3":"Google","4":"24.95","5":"HW"},"4":{"0":"5","1":"Gas Grill","2":"BT04","3":"Apple","4":"149.95","5":"AP"},"5":{"0":"6","1":"Washer","2":"BZ66","3":"Google","4":"399.99","5":"AP"}}

But my required output should be: (only json)

> {"0":{"0":"1","1":"Iron","2":"AX12","3":"Google","4":"21.95","5":"HW"},"1":{"0":"2","1":"DartBoard","2":"AZ52","3":"Apple","4":"12.95","5":"SG"},"2":{"0":"3","1":"BasketBall","2":"BA74","3":"Microsoft","4":"29.95","5":"SG"},"3":{"0":"4","1":"Compopper","2":"BH22","3":"Google","4":"24.95","5":"HW"},"4":{"0":"5","1":"Gas
>   Grill","2":"BT04","3":"Apple","4":"149.95","5":"AP"},"5":{"0":"6","1":"Washer","2":"BZ66","3":"Google","4":"399.99","5":"AP"}}

any suggestions please.

Thanks
Sai

**Solution:**

**PHP:**

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "123456";

try {
        $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=holt", $username, $password);
        $statement=$conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM productdetails");
        $statement->execute();
        $results=$statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        $json=json_encode($results);
        echo $json;
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
?>
```

Thanks for suggestions.

Comment: turn off warnings or switch to PDO

Comment: The error message tells you exactly what to do: use mysqli or PDO instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted in the comments, you should turn off warnings, or better yet, write your code in a manner that doesn't produce warnings.

On turning off warnings:
[Turn off warnings and errors on php/mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1645661/turn-off-warnings-and-errors-on-php-mysql)

You can suppress errors inline with the @ symbol, which is the error control operator in php. Putting @ at the beginning of your mysql_connect() line should get rid of it, but you should switch to PDO!

On PDO (which I recommend and use):
http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access--net-12059

PDO protects you against SQL injection and allows queries to be sent to the database and constructed beforehand, and you send the inputs afterwards via "placeholders".

Comment: I turned off warnings in wamp and updated the code using PDO. Please find the code here. <?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "123456";

try {
  $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=holt", $username, $password);
  $statement=$pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM productdetails");
  $statement->execute();
  $results=$statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  $json=json_encode($results);
  echo $json;
 } catch(PDOException $e) {
  echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
?>

Comment: can you please check it once.

Comment: $statement=$pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM productdetails");
This line should have $conn instead of $pdo, $conn is the name of your DB object.

Comment: It is working fine now after updating $conn rather than $pdo. I will update this in the solution box.

Comment: Great, glad I could help